# Each_Slice on Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am hoping to get a nested array containing individual arrays that have a minimum of three elements but a maximum of four elements. I am running into a problem when I get to 10:

```
example = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

example.each_slice(3).to_a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
example.each_slice(4).to_a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

The desired result is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]       (all arrays have 3 elements but no more than 4)
```

Is each_slice not the way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: There are three possibilities here to split this array that way in this case. One of them is `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]` could you clarify whether it is to be 3-3-4? What in case of 12-element array, should it be all threes or all fours?

Comment: Will [`in_groups_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) help? It guarantees a consistent group size by padding with `nil`s.

Comment: thanks Mark! i had no idea in_groups_of even existed. it looks like this will work!

BroiSatse - sorry, i should have stated that it could be any variation, as long as there's at least three elements and no more than four. in the case of 12, it could be 4-4-4 or 3-3-3-3, either one would work.

Comment: Note that `in_groups_of` is provided by Rails, not Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each_slice produces slices up to the desired size; it isn't going to directly accomplish what you want here, which is kind of a "balancing" of the list. Fortunately, we can get there.

```
list = (1..10).to_a
slice_count = (list.length / 3.0).floor
list.each_slice(slice_count).to_a.each {|l| l.fill nil, slice_count, 0 }.transpose.map(&:compact)
# => [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

This doesn't preserve the ordering, but it does balance the values. The way this works is that it basically creates a matrix of the values where at least the first 3 rows of each column are populated, with the fourth column serving to catch the overflow.

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 -  -
```

Then using #transpose creates arrays out of the columns, which we then compact to remove the nils.

Preserving the order is a bit harder, and will require some if conditions. The desired distribution of arrays with 3/4 elements will impact the answer in that case.

Comment: perfect! i appreciate this Chris! great explanation too. works great

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could do it, which preserves order and maximizes the number of arrays containing three elements, putting zero, one or two arrays of four at the end.

**Code**

```
def divide_up(arr)
  sz = arr.size
  return nil if [0,1,2,5].include?(sz)
  n3, d = sz.divmod(3)
  return arr.each_slice(3).to_a if d.zero?
  return arr.each_slice(4).to_a if d==n3
  n3 -= d
  arr[0,3*n3].each_slice(3).to_a + arr[3*n3..-1].each_slice(4).to_a
end
```

Note `d==n3` in the fifth line of the method is shorthand for `(d==1 && n3==1) || (d==2 && n3==2)`.

**Examples**

```
16.times do |n|
  arr = [*1..n]
  puts "for: #{arr}:"
  a=divide_up(arr)
  puts "  #{(a ? a : "No solution")}"
end
  #=> for: []:
  #     No solution
  #   for: [1]:
  #     No solution
  #   for: [1, 2]:
  #     No solution
  #   for: [1, 2, 3]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
  #     No solution
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
  #   for: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]:
  #     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```